# Get non-json content from AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am trying to simply get the text displayed in the resulting page but it look like this code snipped is looking specifically for JSON only.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"userId": [loggedParent getObjectID]};
[manager POST:@"http://myurl" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
   }];
```

This is the error I get:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=XXXXXXXXX {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

How do I modify my code to simply read and save the text that is displayed?

Comment: What's the output go the `NSLog` statement showing the `responseObject`?

Comment: It never reaches that point, it goes directly to the failure block with the message above.

Comment: What content-type does your server respond with? The error suggests it's a JSON mime-type but not valid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're in AFNetworking 2.0, which I haven't actually used. But it looks like you should be able to modify the responseSerializer property in the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to accept whatever content type your server is sending. AFHTTPResponseSerializer has an acceptableContentTypes field you can modify.

However, given the error you're seeing it seems like the server may be returning an "application/json" content-type but not actually delivering valid JSON content.

Comment: This was the problem.  It was actually expecting JSON in return.  I will update my original code with what I used.